# Windows 8 - Intel Rapid Storage Technology No Accelerate Tab - Move EFI Recovery Partition to HDD

Tags: windows-8, ssd, storage

i have followed few posts in here regarding no accelerate tab in Intel Rapid Storage Technology application, and i am having similar issue. when i installed windows-8, the recovery and efi partitions were created in SSD in stead of HDD, though the OS was installed on HDD.

HDD is 500 GB, has single partition with OS and data, full space allocated to the partition, however i can probably create partitions or free spaces as unallocated for EFI and Recovery partitions. HDD has 300+ GB free space.

SSD is 20 GB, has 2 partitions, 300 MB recovery and 100 MB EFI, the rest is unallocated.

what i understand, in order to get the accelerate tab and working, SSD must have full space unallocated. now this can be done if i can move these partitions to the HDD by any way. i don't want to clean install of Windows-8 again to get all the partitions created in HDD, and not sure whether it would create the partitions in HDD. because during Windows-8 setup, i selected HDD for installation, but the recovery and EFI partitions were created in SSD, i was not sure why did this happen.

now i need help on how can i possibly resolve this situation. is this the only way to get the accelerate tab and working with this by fully unallocating the SSD?

worst case solution - if i need to go for a clean installation of Windows, how do i make sure the recovery and EFI partitions will be created in HDD and not in SSD?

my PC is Acer TimelineU M5-581T, with UEFI motherboard. appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

With the BIOS in RAID mode and the SSD *not* installed, install Windows to the hard drive.

When done powering down, install the SSD, boot into Windows and enable caching. You may need to delete any existing partitions on it first.